# How can I retrieve the outer most points on a 2d graph?

Tags: algorithm

I have a 2d graph which has some points plotted on it.

What I need to do is get only the outer most points so that I can connect them up (isn't really relevant).

What I can't seem to wrap my head around is the algorithm that I need to use in order to do this?

---

I think this might help you understand what I want to achieve:

```
o o o
o x o
o o o
```

All the o's I want to get and the x I want to ignore. Also, the points can be in any position and any shape but I still want to only grab the outer most points.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably looking for the [Graham scan algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graham_scan), a method for finding a convex hull of a set of points.